# Why am I able to add margins to images in css although images are inline element?

Tags: html, css, image, inline, margins

I had read somewhere that since images are inline elements, margins can't be added to them. Using the following code, I was able to add margins to my images. Why is it so?

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Images are replaced elements. Replaced elements have their own rules.

Answer (score 0):

because `<img>` is a replaced element; it has a display value of inline by default, but its default dimensions are defined by the embedded image's intrinsic values like it were inline-block. You can set properties like border/border-radius, padding/margin, width, height, etc. on an `<img>`.